# Switchback LED circuit

Tags: led, switching

I hope someone can help me clarify this situation here.

I found numerous LED switchback circuits, but none of them seemed to work or achieve what I wanted.

I want the white LEDs to be on and when the second DC source is activated it should turn on the yellow LEDs and power on the coil which turns off the white LEDs.

The capacitor keeps the yellow LEDs on a while longer before switching back to white LEDs.

Is this a setup that can work in the real-life scenario, or is there a better way to connect these components to work like I want them to?

Here is the link to Paul Falstad's simulation:

[Paul Falstad simulation](https://tinyurl.com/229gaqqf)

[image]

Comment: What does the diode bring to the party? I doubt this circuit will correctly work so, all we really have is a loose explanation of what you want to achieve.

Comment: I'm fairly new to circuits so I don't know everything about them. The diode is there to prevent reverse current when the signal is turned off.

Comment: The switch will perform that function

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be like this:

It’s better to place yellow Leds parallel to coil, in series the Leds would decrease the relay coil voltage and possibly the relay would not switch on.

1n4007 dissipates the relay coil energy when SW is opened.

Pick the resistors according Leds rated current.

[image]